# How to insert data from tbl2.data2 to tbl1.data1 where tbl1.data1 = '000'

Tags: sql, mysql

2 tables tbl1(A) and tbl2(B)

tbl1(A): id is primary key and indexed

```
id,  name,  data1
------------------
1,     a,        111
2,     b,        222
3,     c,        000
```

tbl2(B): id is primary key and indexed

```
id  data2
----------
1,   333
```

after button click
tbl1(A):

```
id,  name,  data1
------------------
1,     a,        111
2,     b,        222
3,     c,        333
```

Comment: I tried ---> INSERT INTO tbl1(data1)
                  SELECT tbl2.data2
                  FROM tbl2
                  WHERE tbl1.data1 = '000'

Comment: you need to use update not insert, but what happend if there are multiple 000 in the table

Comment: it cant have a multiple 000

Comment: nothing happends ---> UPDATE tbl1 AS t1
INNER JOIN tbl2 AS t2
ON t1.data1 = t2.data2 
SET t1.data1 = t2.data2
WHERE t1.data1 = '000'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use pattern.
When you know which number you will insert, you can simply use a subwuery to catch it.

For more values you need patterns to get the right numbers in the correct rows, or you need to run every update on its own

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(1), `data1` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO TableA
    (`id`, `name`, `data1`)
VALUES
    (1, 'a', 111),
    (2, 'b', 222),
    (3, 'c', 000)
;
```

```
CREATE TABLE TableB
    (`id` int, `data2` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO TableB
    (`id`, `data2`)
VALUES
    ('1', 333)
;
```

```
UPDATE
TableA SET `data1` = (SELECT `data2` FROM TableB WHERE id = 1) 
WHERE `data1` = 000
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
```

| id | name | data1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 111 |
| 2 | b | 222 |
| 3 | c | 333 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VXVGCyzw)